# How to find number of retries in Argo workflow

Tags: devops, kubernetes-cronjob, argo-workflows

I'm having an Argo workflow with

```
retryStrategy:
  limit: "2"
  retryPolicy: Always
```

If my workflow fails, it will be retried again 2 times, so is there any way by which I can know how many times my workflow was retried before getting passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way by which I can know how many times my workflow was retried before getting passed.

`retryStrategy` doesn't retry Worfklows. It retries tasks/steps within Workflows. If a step/task within a workflow fails, it will be retried according to the template's `retryStrategy` (or the default `retryStrategy` defined at the Workflow level if none is defined at the template level).

There are many ways to check retry counts. Here are a few:

1. Argo CLI

   ```sh
   argo submit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/master/examples/retry-on-error.yaml -n argo
   argo get @latest -n argo
   ```

   ```
   Name:                retry-on-error-6dmcq
   Namespace:           argo
   ServiceAccount:      default
   Status:              Succeeded
   Conditions:
     PodRunning          False
     Completed           True
   Created:             Fri Dec 10 09:42:36 -0500 (1 minute ago)
   Started:             Fri Dec 10 09:42:36 -0500 (1 minute ago)
   Finished:            Fri Dec 10 09:42:56 -0500 (1 minute ago)
   Duration:            20 seconds
   Progress:            2/2
   ResourcesDuration:   4s*(1 cpu),4s*(100Mi memory)

     STEP                          TEMPLATE         PODNAME                          DURATION  MESSAGE
     ✔ retry-on-error-6dmcq       error-container
     ├─✖ retry-on-error-6dmcq(0)  error-container  retry-on-error-6dmcq-1358267989  3s        Error (exit code 3)
     └─✔ retry-on-error-6dmcq(1)  error-container  retry-on-error-6dmcq-1157083656  3s
   ```

   The step failed once and then succeeded.
2. Argo UI

   The Argo web UI has a similar presentation. The graph will branch, and failed attempts will appear as leaf nodes marked as failed.
3. Other

   You could inspect the Workflow object and analyze the nodes to find failures associated with retries.

   ```sh
   kubectl get wf retry-on-error-6dmcq -n argo -ojson
   ```

   You could also look at app logs for repetition from the step in question.